# T-SQL find string with lowercase and uppercase

Tags: t-sql

I have a database with several tables and I need to search **every** `varchar` column across the database, for columns that simultaneously contain lower and upper case characters.

To clarify:

If one column contains `helLo` the **name of the column** should be returned by the query, but if the column values only contain either `hello` or `HELLO` then the name of the column is not returned.

Answer (score 9):

Let's exclude all UPPER and all LOWER, the rest will be MIXED.

```
SELECT someColumn
FROM someTable
WHERE someColumn <> UPPER(someColumn) AND someColumn <> LOWER(someColumn)
```

**EDIT**:

As suggested [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39149591/t-sql-find-string-with-lowercase-and-uppercase/39150355#comment65644319_39150355) and described in detail [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1032/case-sensitive-search-on-a-case-insensitive-sql-server/) I need to specify a case-sensitive collation.

```
SELECT someColumn
FROM someTable
WHERE someColumn <> UPPER(someColumn) AND 
      someColumn <> LOWER(someColumn) 
      Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Comment: HA! Brilliant and cleaner than my answer... well done sir.

Comment: In most cases one would expect `a==A` without a collation hint.

Comment: How does this answer actually answer the question being asked?  You would need to manually run this query on every single `varchar` column held in the database...

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are after a case sensitive search, so you'd need to use a case sensitive collation for there WHERE clause.

e.g. if your collation is currently SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS which is case insensitive, you can write a case sensitive query using:

```
SELECT SomeColumn
FROM dbo.SomeTable
WHERE SomeField LIKE '%helLo%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Here, `COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS` tells it to use a case sensitive collation to perform the filtering.

Comment: Thank you Ada but I can't search only for hello string I need to find if a column contains a string with mixed lowercase and uppercase characters.....not only the hello string.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the hash compared to its upper and lower values... here is a simple test:

```
declare @test varchar(256)
set @test = 'MIX' -- Try changing this to a mix case, and then all lower case

select case
            when hashbytes('SHA1',@test) <> hashbytes('SHA1',upper(@test)) and hashbytes('SHA1',@test) <> hashbytes('SHA1',lower(@test))
            then 'MixedCase'
            else 'Not Mixed Case'
        end
```

So using this in a table... you can do something like this

```
create table #tempT (SomeColumn varchar(256))
insert into #tempT (SomeColumn) values ('some thing lower'),('SOME THING UPPER'),('Some Thing Mixed')

SELECT SomeColumn
FROM #tempT
WHERE 1 = case
            when hashbytes('SHA1',SomeColumn) <> hashbytes('SHA1',upper(SomeColumn)) and hashbytes('SHA1',SomeColumn) <> hashbytes('SHA1',lower(SomeColumn)) then 1
            else 0
          end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand that you want to find any varchar column with mixed case data within it?

If so, you can achieve this with a `cursor` looking at your column types, which then executes some dynamic SQL on the `varchar` columns it finds to check the data for mixed case values.

I thoroughly recommend doing this on a non-production server using a copy of your database, not least because you need to create a table to deposit your findings into:

```
create table VarcharColumns (TableName nvarchar(max), ColumnName nvarchar(max))

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

declare my_cursor cursor local static read_only forward_only
for 
select 'insert into VarcharColumns select t,c from(select ''' + s.name + '.' + tb.name + ''' t, ''' + c.name + ''' c from ' + s.name + '.' + tb.name + ' where ' + c.name + ' like ''%[abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]%'' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS and ' + c.name + ' like ''%[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]%'' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS having count(1) > 0) a' as s
from sys.columns c
    inner join sys.types t
        on(c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
            and t.name = 'varchar'
            )
    inner join sys.tables tb
        on(c.object_id = tb.object_id)
    inner join sys.schemas s
        on(tb.schema_id = s.schema_id)

open my_cursor
fetch next from my_cursor into @sql
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin 
    print @sql
    exec(@sql)
    fetch next from my_cursor into @sql
end
close my_cursor
deallocate my_cursor

select * from VarcharColumns
```

Comment: Thought his may return the desired results (i haven't tested) it would be detrimental for performance. Cursor's should be used as a last resort (most of the time) and at all cost... shouldn't be row based.

Comment: @scsimon Indeed.  Cursors are very bad performance wise, though this doesn't look like a BAU task that will be run regularly.  In this case, I think getting the right result once is more important than getting it in the most efficient manner.  In addition, this also looks to be over a small number of tables, so this will at most have a few hundred records to process.  If this was on a huge database, maintaining a list of the `case` statements mentioned by the other answers would take more manual time than it would database time.