# Find String Name that contain KATE word in CAPITAL Letter, not in small letter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am KATE OutPut: It will return String Name in OutPut

I am Kate OutPut: It will not return String Name in OutPut

Comment: Please update with the SQL that you have tried so we may best help you here without so much guessing

Comment: See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Note that `SELECT 'kate' = 'KATE';` returns `1` in MySQL

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39149591/t-sql-find-string-with-lowercase-and-uppercase

Answer (score 3):

I am going to simply put up a guess, you can collate the query (or the column in the database) using a case sensitive collation

```
SELECT *
FROM MyfunTable
WHERE name LIKE '%KATE%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```